# GetLeft of a Path in a canvas

Tags: path

I am trying to find the Left of a Path using Canvas.GetLeft(aPath);
But i am getting a 0.
I have tried calling aPath.Measure and got the DesiredSize successfully which has the width but is there any way i could get the left of a aPath.
Please help.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and found that using the VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset() worked:

```
Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(myPath);

//moving the path around the canvus just a bit
Canvas.SetTop(myPath, offset.X + 100);
Canvas.SetLeft(myPath, offset.Y + 100);
```

Good luck!